# Access a Windows 2008 server HDD from Centos 6.7

Tags: linux, mount, windows

One of my co-workers has a hard drive with Windows 2008 server **that does not boot all** and we need to access certain files in the OS so then it can boot properly.  Does anyone know how can I access those files without harming the rest of the content on the Windows 2008 OS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the HD where Windows 2008 Server is installed is an internal one. In this case, you can just put it inside an [HD external case](https://www.google.com/search?q=external%20hdd%20case) and access it on Linux via USB just like an external device. Linux easily recognizes all common Windows filesystem types.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to download a live cd like SystemRescueCD (http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) and follow the instructions to mount a NTFS partition from http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Mounting_an_NTFS_partition_with_full_Read-Write_support which basically says to do:

```
ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows
```

Where `/dev/sda1` is the partition you want to mount. Use `fdisk -l` to get a list of disks/partitions seen by the OS.